# AXLSX_RAILS converting html to text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I'm saving Rails data into an Excel spreadsheet using the gem AXLSX_RAILS.

I have some text fields that are stored as HTML in the database.

This is my attempt to convert the HTML to text:

```
      sheet.add_row ['REVENUE DESCRIPTION', strip_tags(@costproject.revenue).gsub!("&nbsp;", "")]
```

That works to remove the HTML tags.

But, I would like to replace `&nbsp;` with the Excel new line (code 10 - vbLf).

How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
      sheet.add_row ['DESCRIPTION', strip_tags(@costproject.description).gsub!("&nbsp;", vbLf)]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "\x0A". Something like:

```
sheet.add_row ['REVENUE DESCRIPTION', strip_tags(@costproject.revenue).gsub!("&nbsp;", "\x0A")]
```

That should be the Hex equivalent of vbLF. [See this reference](http://mc-computing.com/languages/CR_LF.htm).

If you want both carriage return and line feed, use "\x0D\x0A".

Incidentally, I do not see any constant within Axlsx.